# Mailchimp custom merge tags not working in some forms

Tags: mailchimp

I have defined few custom merge tags in Mailchimp for testing. Those tags work fine while sending campaigns.

Output from campaign (in email):

```
Testing Merge Tags
Email: mail@FOO.co.uk
First name: FOO
Just Testing: Testing
Language ID: 0
```

But same merge tags do not work (except email address) in some forms like "Opt-in Confirmation Email" or "Unsubscribe Form" in **advanced mode** (I have not tested other forms).

Output from Unsubscribe Form:

```
Email: mail@FOO.co.uk  
First name: 
Just Testing: 
Language ID:
```

The code bellow was used to test those merge tags:

```
Testing Merge Tags
Email: *|EMAIL|*
First name: *|FNAME|*
Just Testing: *|MMERGE3|*
Language ID: *|LANG_ID|*
```

I am wondering if this is a bug within Mailchimp?

Thanks.

Comment: It may sound silly, but are you sure that you're unsubscribing from the same list that you tested the campaign sending to?  Also, I'd recommend going to MailChimp support if you haven't already.